# My (element.is(':visible')) condition is never true

Tags: javascript, jquery

For a FAQs section, my JS code checks whether the answer to the question clicked is visible and closes it if that's the case or opens it otherwise. But for some reason the `(this_answer.is(':visible'))` condition is never true, even when the answer has been made visible by now by the `fadeIn()` line in the code below. Why?

JS:

```
$('.faq_question').click(function(){
  $('.faq_answer').fadeOut(0);
  var this_answer = $(this).siblings('.faq_answer');
  if (this_answer.is(':visible'))
    this_answer.fadeOut(0);
  else
    this_answer.fadeIn(0);
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class='faq_question'>
      Question #1
    </div>
    <div class='faq_answer'>
      Answer #1
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class='faq_question'>
      Question #2
    </div>
    <div class='faq_answer'>
      Answer #2
    </div>
  </li>
  ...
```

Comment: It's never true because you've called `fadeOut()` literally 2 lines before. Also `fadeOut(0)` is pretty redundant, just use `hide()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fading all the answer elements out immediately, so they can't be visible right after that.

But, it appears that you may be trying to hide all the answers initially and then show them when the corresponding question is clicked. To do this, you should hide all the answers outside of the question click code and because you are using JQuery, just use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to show/hide the answers without having to write any `if/then` code.

Also, as others point out in the comments below. `.fadeOut(0)` has the same effect as `.hide()`, which is more straight-forward.

```js
// Hide all the answers initially:
$('.faq_answer').hide();

$('.faq_question').click(function(){
  // Just toggle the visibility of the answer(s) that
  // correspond with the clicked question.
  $(this).siblings('.faq_answer').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class='faq_question'>
      Question #1
    </div>
    <div class='faq_answer'>
      Answer #1
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class='faq_question'>
      Question #2
    </div>
    <div class='faq_answer'>
      Answer #2
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `fadeOut(0)` == `hide()` :) Might as well use `toggle(booleanexpression)` or just toggle()

Comment: @GoneCoding Yes, but that is not actually relevant to the question.

Comment: It is relevant to improve whatever needs improving :)

Comment: I take (both of) your points, but the use of `fade` is not relevant to the problem or answer. Yes, it's nice to have a more complete answer, but I've had just as many people on SO complain that answers try to answer too much that is not relevant to the question being asked and I've had people comment that all aspects of the code should be improved in an answer. In the end, the OPs question is the foremost thing to be addressed.  PS: I normally post a direct answer first and then edit the answer to be more comprehensive later.

Comment: Just to be clear, you changed it to `toggle` after my comment to use `toggle`, but thank you for implying I copied you. Well done :)

Comment: No, just to be clear, I changed line #1 from `fadeOut(0)` to `hide()` after your comment and then credited you in the answer. `.toggle()` was my answer from the beginning. In fact, if my memory serves me, you didn't mention anything about `.toggle()` in your original comment. You edited that in later.

Comment: Your memory is not what is used to be. It was there from the start. I added the shorter version after, but this is all pointless: Take what you want and insinuate as your please.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you are hiding the item before checking if it is hidden. You can reduce it all to this:

```
// hide all the answers first
$('.faq_answer').hide();

// A single delegated event handler is more efficient
$(document).on('click', '.faq_question', function(){

   // Toggle the matching answer for the clicked question
   $(this).siblings('.faq_answer').toggle();
});
```